# How to mock a function defined in a module of a package?

Tags: python, mocking

I've got a following structure:

```
|-- dirBar
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- bar.py
|-- foo.py
`-- test.py
```

bar.py

```
def returnBar():
    return 'Bar'
```

foo.py

```
from dirBar.bar import returnBar

def printFoo():
    print returnBar()
```

test.py

```
from mock import Mock

from foo import printFoo
from dirBar import bar

bar.returnBar = Mock(return_value='Foo')

printFoo()
```

the result of `python test.py` is `Bar`.

How to mock the `printBar` to make it return `Foo` so that `printFoo` will print it?

EDIT: Without modifying any other file that `test.py`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm guessing you are going to mock the function `returnBar`, you'd like to use [`patch` decorator](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html):

```
from mock import patch

from foo import printFoo

@patch('foo.returnBar')
def test_printFoo(mockBar):
    mockBar.return_value = 'Foo'
    printFoo()

test_printFoo()
```

Comment: The missing piece is that you patch the function at the place it is imported *to*, not the place it is imported *from*. After you import as `from dirBar.bar import returnBar` in `foo.py`, the mocking needs to patch the import as `foo.returnBar`, not as `dirBar.bar.returnBar`.

Comment: @hughdbrown `The basic principle is that you patch where an object is looked up, which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined. A couple of examples will help to clarify this.` http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#id1

Comment: @hughdbrown That was it.. I was wondering why my mock was not working. Kudos to the tip there

Comment: It took me a while to fully get the sentence "you patch the function at the place it is imported to, not the place it is imported from. ". If you have a function in a module just forget the name of the module and focus on where the call you want to mock. If you have an import in a class or module A. Then mock A.your_function.

Answer (score 32):

Just import the `bar` module before the `foo` module and mock it:

```
from mock import Mock

from dirBar import bar
bar.returnBar = Mock(return_value='Foo')

from foo import printFoo

printFoo()
```

When you are importing the `returnBar` in `foo.py`, you are binding the value of the module to a variable called `returnBar`. This variable is local so is put in the closure of the `printFoo()` function when `foo` is imported - and the values in the closure cannot be updated by code from outiside it. So, it should have the new value (that is, the mocking function) *before* the importing of `foo`.

**EDIT**: the previous solution workis but is not robust since it depends on ordering the imports. That is not much ideal. Another solution (that occurred me after the first one) is to import the `bar` module in `foo.py` instead of only import the `returnBar()` function:

```
from dirBar import bar

def printFoo():
    print bar.returnBar()
```

This will work because the `returnBar()` is now retrieved directly from the `bar` module instead of the closure. So if I update the module, the new function will be retrieved.

Comment: Yes the problem was - I had the code like that and idn't wanted to change them. After a discussion on freenode#python I've decided to refactor the other file (here foo.py) so it will be better and cleaner

Comment: @zalun is there a link to this discussion? I am curious about that!

Comment: In a surprising turn of affairs, I got a bit annoyed of following my advice myself and create a ctx manager/decorator to mock attributes in modules: https://github.com/confeitaria/inelegant/blob/master/readme.rst#the-temp_var-context-manager-and-decorator Maybe it can be useful for someone, or one can use it as a reference. That said, avoiding dependencies are a good idea still IMHO; I just did that because I do have this dependency on a lot of projects!

Answer (score -3):

Another way to deal with those case is to use some dependency injection.

An easy way to do it in python is to use the magical `**kwargs` :

foo.py

```
from dirBar.bar import returnBar

def printFoo(**kwargs):
    real_returnBar = kwargs.get("returnBar", returnBar)
    print real_returnBar()
```

test.py

```
from mock import Mock

from foo import printFoo
from dirBar import bar

mocked_returnBar = Mock(return_value='Foo')

printFoo(returnBar=mocked_returnBar)
```

this will lead to a more testable code (and increase modularity/reusability).

Comment: the whole idea is to not modify anything except of test.py